# How to compare dates in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

There is a table with fields containing unix timestamps, and I was trying to get records that are older than one hour with

```
select * from table_name where (date('now','unixepoch') - table_field) > 3600
```

But this doesn’t show any records at all, but there *are* fields containing stamps of the time of days ago. If there is some simple condition like `table_field > 1` it does output all the records. But why the statement at the top doesn’t work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'unixepoch'` modifier converts from a Unix timestamp number to a format that the `date` function understands.
However, you want to convert from a date string to a Unix timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE strftime('%s', 'now') - field > 3600
```

Instead of counting seconds, you could also use a [modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) (but without the subtraction, the string returned by `strftime` is not automatically converted into a number):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE CAST(strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 hours') AS INT) > field
```